# SharePoint List "Filter By" pane is not respecting View Filters?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, filter, sharepoint-list-filter

I have created a SharePoint List several months ago, this list includes several filtered views - both for usability purposes, and to avoid hitting the 5000 lines threshold.

We have data for different region-product combinations on each view.
Up until last Friday, everything has worked properly for months. However, now - after no apparent change made by the List owners - the filter by pane is acting up.

For specific views (all not-affected views are built exactly the same as the ones that are affected - the only change is the value on the view filter), the Filter By pane is showing all available data items, instead of showing only the ones that apply to the current view, ie:

I have a view with the data below:

| Market | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Market 1 | Product A |
| Market 1 | Product B |

When I go to the Market header and click on "Filter By", the pane then shows up other markets - even when the view is filtered to show Market 1 only.

Filter By 'Market':

□ null
□ Market 1
□ Market 2
□ Market 3
□ Market 4

These other markets do exist on the list, but the view filter should filter them out before the column filter is triggered - and up until last Friday was doing so.

Comment: I think something changed at Microsoft end. I have seen few other users also facing similar issue.

Comment: Agree with @Ganesh Sanap, you can open a ticket with MS. They will help you check from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check is "Market" an indexed column, if not please try to make the columns as indexed and check the filter